# Listable (on certain level) custom function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, attributes

I wish to make custom listable function (for 2D points) with the next behaviour:

```
myf[{x_, y_}] := {doSmth@x, doSmth@y};
pts = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}, ...};  
myf[pts] === {myf[{x1,y1}], myf[{x2,y2}], ...}
```

I'm going to do huge calculations, and read this in documentation:

> To apply a function to a vector, take advantage of Listable functions when possible

And there is example that `Listable` without `Map` works ~10 times faster.

But when I set

```
Attributes[myf] = {Listable}
```

I get

```
 myf[pts] === {{myf[x1], myf[y1]}, {myf[x2], myf[y2]}, ...}
```

which is not what is needed ((

Comment: Are  you aware of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98055/106)?

Comment: @user1066, Hmm,I should think it over, but I'm not going to use some packed arrays

Comment: And the behavior you want can be easily achieved with `Compile`, but to use `Compile` properly we need to know what's that `doSmth`, so please make the question more specific.

Comment: One usual trick is to pack a pair of `{xk, yk}` as a complex number `zk := xk + yk I`, then define a Listable function to be used on `{z1, z2, ...}`.

Comment: if `myf` is already listable, it will automatically map. for example: ```myf = (#+1)*2&;

myf@{{1,2},{3,4}}```

Answer (score 2):

```
pts = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}};
```

Just use `Map`:

```
Map[myf, pts]
```

{myf[{x1, y1}], myf[{x2, y2}]}

Or define

```
mf[x_] := Map[myf, x]

mf[pts]
```

{myf[{x1, y1}], myf[{x2, y2}]}

Comment: Thank you, maybe, but please look at edited question

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Rather than use the attribute [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), define `myf` as

```
myf[x_?VectorQ] := doSmth /@ x;

myf[x_List] := myf /@ x
```

Then

```
pts = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 4]

(* {{x[1], y[1]}, {x[2], y[2]}, {x[3], y[3]}, {x[4], y[4]}} *)

myf[pts]

(* {{doSmth[x[1]], doSmth[y[1]]}, {doSmth[x[2]], 
  doSmth[y[2]]}, {doSmth[x[3]], doSmth[y[3]]}, {doSmth[x[4]], 
  doSmth[y[4]]}} *)
```